# AngularJS: Custom directive is not correctly computing data requirements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building a custom directive to allow for a glyphicon to serve as an indicator (color), a notice (tooltip), a simple action (single click) and an ability for customized action in a modal (double click).

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HrlhlbcCdCzZHwD8JivQ?p=preview) of my progress.

On first load the colors are correct -- gray if value = 0, green for value of 1 and red for value of 2. The click also is correct -- a 0 clicked becomes 1, a 1 clicked becomes 2 and a 2 clicked becomes 1.

However, the colors are not responding correctly to the clicks. The first click seems to be ignored because the color stays the same and the second click does trigger a color change but now 1 = red and 2 = green (backwards).

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong that would make the color scheme fail?

Here is the code from the plunker --

app.js

```
(function() {
  angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .directive('sglclick', SingleClickDirective)
    .directive('loanProgressIcon', LoanProgressIconDirective)
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

  function SingleClickDirective($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var fn = $parse(attr['sglclick']);
        var delay = 300,
          clicks = 0,
          timer = null;
        element.on('click', function(event) {
          clicks++; //count clicks
          if (clicks === 1) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
              fn(scope, {
                $event: event
              });
            clicks = 0; //after action performed, reset counter
            }, delay);
          } else {
            clearTimeout(timer); //prevent single-click action
            clicks = 0; //after action performed, reset counter
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }

  function LoanProgressIconDirective($compile) {
    var progressMarkers = [{
      'id': 1,
      'cat': 'its_list',
      'glyph': 'list-alt',
      'tip': 'ITS List Verfified'
    }, {
      'id': 2,
      'cat': 'fsa_compliant',
      'glyph': 'home',
      'tip': 'FSA Eligibility'

    }, {
      'id': 3,
      'cat': 'has_liens',
      'glyph': 'star',
      'tip': 'Prior Lien Verfied'
    }, {
      'id': 4,
      'cat': 'valid_leases',
      'glyph': 'leaf',
      'tip': 'Leases Valid'
    }];

    var statusColors = [
      { val: 0, color: '#CCC', class: 'pending'},
      { val: 1, color: '#006837', class: 'completed'},
      { val: 2, color: '#900', class: 'overdue'}
    ];

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require : 'ngModel',
      link: linker,
      templateUrl: 'loanProgress.html',
      scope: {
        cat: '@',
        ngModel: '='
      }
    };

    function linker(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.loan = {
        id: progressMarkers[scope.cat]['id'],
        glyphicon: progressMarkers[scope.cat]['glyph'],
        tooltip: progressMarkers[scope.cat]['tip']
      };

      var styleChange = function () {
        scope.loan.style = statusColors[scope.ngModel]['color'];
      };

      styleChange();

      var setter = ctrl.$setViewValue;

      ctrl.$setViewValue = function() {
          setter.apply(this, arguments);
          styleChange();
      };

      scope.progClicked = function() {

        if(parseInt(scope.ngModel) === 0){
          ctrl.$setViewValue(1);
        } else if(parseInt(scope.ngModel) === 1){
          ctrl.$setViewValue(2);
        } else if(parseInt(scope.ngModel) === 2){
          ctrl.$setViewValue(1);
        }
      };

      scope.progDblClicked = function() {
        alert('Icon ' + scope.ngModel + ' was double clicked.');
      };
    }
  }

  function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.loan = {
      its_list: 1,
      fsa_compliant: 2,
      has_liens: 1,
      valid_leases: 0
    };
  }
})();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.0.2" data-semver="3.0.2" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.4" data-semver="1.2.4" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="0.11.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.0.2" data-semver="3.0.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="4" class="text-left">LOAN PROGRESS ICONS</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>ITS</th>
                <th>FSA</th>
                <th>LIEN</th>
                <th>LEASES</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span loan-progress-icon cat="0" ng-model="loan.its_list"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span loan-progress-icon cat="1" ng-model="loan.fsa_compliant"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span loan-progress-icon cat="2" ng-model="loan.has_liens"></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <span loan-progress-icon cat="3" ng-model="loan.valid_leases"></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <p>{{loan | json}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Directive Template:

```
<span sglclick="progClicked()" ng-dblclick="progDblClicked()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{loan.glyphicon}}" tooltip="{{loan.tooltip}}" style="font-size:18px;color:{{loan.style}};cursor:pointer;"></span>
```

and app.css

```
th, td{
  text-align:center;
}

.row{
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.completed{
  color: #006837;
}
.pending{
  color: #CCCCCC;
}
.overdue{
  color: #990000;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is due to the fact that `on` is a jqLite/jQuery method and does not trigger the digest loop for you. This means that the UI will not be updated to reflect the changes to the model.

You either need to wrap the code that affects the model in a call to `$apply` or use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`.

With `$apply`:

```
timer = setTimeout(function() {
  scope.$apply(fn(scope, {
    $event: event
  }));
  clicks = 0;
}, delay);
```

With `$timeout`:

```
element.on('click', function(event) {
  clicks++; //count clicks
  if (clicks === 1) {
    timer = $timeout(function() {
      fn(scope, {
        $event: event
      });
      clicks = 0;
    }, delay);
  } else {
    $timeout.cancel(timer); //prevent single-click action
    clicks = 0; //after action performed, reset counter
  }
});
```

The second issue is the following code:

```
var setter = ctrl.$setViewValue;

ctrl.$setViewValue = function() {
    setter.apply(this, arguments);
    styleChange();
};
```

After calling `$setViewValue` the internal ngModelWatch will not detect the change and update the ngModel in your directive until later when the digest loop runs. Currently `styleChange` runs before this happens.

To run `styleChange` after the digest loop has finished you can use `$timeout`:

```
ctrl.$setViewValue = function() {
  setter.apply(this, arguments);
  $timeout(styleChange);
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/5MfQk49NKWFiEOqS2r5V?p=preview

Comment: Very nice explanation ... I wish you wrote the tutorials and courses on Angular that I am using to try to learn this!

Comment: Glad I could help and thank you for the kind words :)